# insert picture between two text

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

how i can insert a logo between two text inside QTextEdit with using Qt4 , i write this code , i need to set alignment for text on left , logo center and the other text right :

```
    self.printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
    self.printer.setPaperSource(self.printer.Middle)
    self.printer.setPageSize(self.printer.A4)        
    self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor()
    self.cursor = self.text.textCursor()
    self.text.append("some text left alignment")
    self.text.append("some text rigth alignment")
    self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
    self.image = QtGui.QTextImageFormat()
    self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.image.setName("leaf.jpg")
```

this code doesn't work , can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The QTextEdit control accept also html, so you can try to format the text using it, probably using a table.

Another way can be to use a QTextDocument and use the drawText and drawImage method, but this require to know (or at least to calculate) the size of the image and of the text to be able to specify the coordinates.

bye
Gianluca

Comment: Thanks For replay , i used a table , but i want to ask you if i can make a Header and Footer for my printing page using QTextDocument ??

Comment: AFAIK not automatically. You must use drawText & drawImage to put text and images in the right place.